# Убрать фон alert dialog

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-customview, android-alertdialog

Создаю диалог по `custom_view`. Все `width` = `wrap_content`, однако, сам диалог, его фон белого цвета и `match_parent`. Как избавиться от цвета, установить прозрачный и изменить ширину?

```
val dialog = with(Builder(this.context, R.style.ProgressDialogTheme)) {
    setView(R.layout.load_alert_dialog)
    setCancelable(false)
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    create()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По каким-то причинам не работали другие решения.
Мой вариант:

1. Добавить в `themes.xml`.

```
<style name="ProgressDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">0dp</item>
</style>
```

2. Для фона диалога можно воспользоваться `@android:color/transparent` или добавить эту же строку в `colors.xml`.
3. В `your_custom_dialog.xml` управлять `background` и т.д.